# Justify the output of bahavior of 'or' keyword

Tags: python

Consider the statement below:

Prob 1:

```
>>> a="abc"
>>> 'd' or 'e' in a
'd'
```

Someone please explain this . I was expecting a True or False ...

Prob 2:

```
>>> print any(c in a for c in 'da')
True
```

Whats happening here ? If i do this ,

```
>>> (c in a for c in 'da')
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x011E4300>
```

As you can see , it gives generator object...What role does 'any' (method,function ??) play 
here? And the result ?

Prob 3:

```
>>> Pattern="sdfdfg"
>>> if '\\'or '^' or '.' in Pattern:
    print "yes"
else:print "no"

yes
```

How on earth is this "YES" ??

Show me the light someone plz...........

Comment: You can find all the light you want [**here**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), [**here**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#any), [**here**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) (all coming from [**here**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/genindex.html)) and some very very bright light [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+tutorial).

Comment: This marks the second time I've seen some one use `a or b in c` (mistaken) for `a in c or b in c` (correct), or more generally `any(d in c for d in [a,b])` (also correct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results you are seeing are the result of the precedence of the `or` and `in` operators being different than you expect.

- `'d' or 'e' in a`

This should be read as `'d' or ('e' in a)`, that is, the 2 operands to `or` are `'d'` and `('e' in a)`. Since [`d` is considered a true value](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in python, `or` *doesn't look at its next operand*, and just returns its first operand, `'d'`. Note that this means that `or` isn't just a logical OR, it can deal with other types, and return other types.

- `print any(c in a for c in 'da')`

Read this `print any((c in a) for c in 'da')`, ie, go over the elementns of `'da'`, test if that letter is also in `a`, and then see if that held true for any of them. The reason you see `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x011E4300>` is that Python does not show you the elements of a generator unless it has cause to step over them. If you want to see the individual elements, write:

```
[(c in a) for c in 'da']
```

- `if '\\'or '^' or '.' in Pattern:`

Again, read this `if ('\\' or '^') or ('.' in Pattern:)`. Since `'\\'` is true, the result is true.

[Table of precedence](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary)

Comment: Minor thing: Last condition would be read as `'\\' or ('^' or ('.' in Pattern))`. The conclusion is still correct.

Comment: According to [the python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary) `or` is left-associative.

Answer (score 4):

**Prob 1.**

`'d' or 'e' in a` is parsed as `'d' or ('e' in a)`. The first one, `'d'` is `True`, so the next part is not considered ([short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)). So it is `'d'`.

To check for both, you can write: `any(c in a for c in 'de')`, like prob 2.

**Prob 2.**

```
>>> (c in a for c in 'da').__class__
<type 'generator'>
>>> any.__class__
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> help(any)
Help on built-in function any in module __builtin__:

any(...)
    any(iterable) -> bool

    Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.
```

[`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) is a function that works on an iterable and returns a boolean value.

**Prob 3.**

The same situation as Prob 1.

Comment: Super .....Prob 1 solved........Thanks dude...eh....FlopCoder...
But this raises another que....if we do wana check for 'd' or 'e' both , then what can we do?

Comment: You check for 'd', and then you check for 'e'.

Answer (score 1):

Prob 1:

You're test is being evaluated to:

```
'd' or ('e' in a)
```

Since 'd' is evaluated as "true", 'd' is the result of the expression.

Prob 2:

any checks if any of the elements on the given iterable object evaluate to true. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any

Prob 3:

Same as prob 1, basically

```
'\\'or '^' or '.' in Pattern
```

equals to

```
'\\'or ('^' or '.' in Pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

Prob 2:

A generator is something you can iterate through without having it all in memory ahead of time.

That particular generator yields a boolean for each character in 'da'.  It is true if and only if that character is also in `a`.

`any` simply returns True if anything in an iterable is truthy.  `'a'` is in `a` , so it returns true because of that character.

You can convert a generator to a list:

```
list(c in a for c in 'da')
```

Comment: Thank you sir, Prob 2 solved....
So how does this 'any' function work? I guess this iterates on all and if a match is found , it returns true and breaks out....Right?

Comment: @arindamroychowdhury, exactly.  You can see [effective code](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) for it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Python objects and many custom ones evaluate to True or False when treated as booleans. In the case of a string, every non-empty string is True. Python evaluates only as much of the logical expression as it must and returns the last item evaluated. So 'd' or 'e' returns 'd' since 'd' is true which guarantees the or being true.

A generator expression just returns an iterator. You can see it with list(_). any prints true if any member of the argument is true.

The third example illustrates a grouping bug. You are asking whether any of the first two arguments are non-empty or '.' is in Pattern. Since the strings are non-empty, it's true.

Comment: *All objects have a True or False equivalent.* Well, many objects are true or false in a boolean context.

Answer (score 0):

Probem 1:

'd' is considered True, so the rest of the expression is skipped.
use bool('d' or ...) if you need True or False.

Probem 2:

```
def any(it):
  for f in it:
     if f:
       return True
  return False
```

Probem 3: 
python sees this as

```
>>> if '\\'or '^' or ('.' in Pattern):
    print "yes"
else:print "no"
```

use

```
if re.search(r"[\\^.]",Pattern):
   ...
```